# A command line reader buffering the commands in Java - follow-up

Tags: java, console

This question elaborates on [A command line reader buffering the commands in Java](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/171140/a-command-line-reader-buffering-the-commands-in-java).

I have essentially hacked the entire code into classes and interfaces.

**CommandLineReader.java**

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;
import net.coderodde.command.line.CommandListener;
import net.coderodde.command.line.AbstractCommandProvider;
import net.coderodde.command.line.support.BufferedCommandProvider;

/**
 * This class implements a command reader via standard input.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jul 26, 2017)
 */
public final class CommandLineReader {

    /**
     * The quit command.
     */
    private static final String QUIT_COMMAND = "quit";

    /**
     * The command line prompt.
     */
    private static final String PROMPT = "> ";

    /**
     * The command provider.
     */
    private final AbstractCommandProvider commandProvider;

    /**
     * Indicates whether the user requested the exit from the loop.
     */
    private boolean done = false;

    /**
     * The scanner for reading the lines.
     */
    private final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    /**
     * Constructs a command line reader with given command provider.
     * 
     * @param commandProvider the command provider.
     */
    public CommandLineReader(AbstractCommandProvider commandProvider) {
        this.commandProvider = Objects.requireNonNull(
                               commandProvider,
                               "The input command provider is null."); 
    }

    /**
     * Runs the program.
     */
    public void run() {
        CommandListener commandListener1 = (String command) -> {
            System.out.println(
                    command + commandProvider.getCommandSeparator());

            if (command.equals(QUIT_COMMAND)) {
                done = true;
            }
        };

        CommandListener commandListener2 = (String command) -> {
            System.err.println(
                    command + commandProvider.getCommandSeparator());
        };  

        commandProvider.addCommandListener(commandListener2);
        commandProvider.addCommandListener(commandListener1);

        while (!done) {
            System.out.print(PROMPT);
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            commandProvider.processLine(line);
        }

        System.out.println("Bye!");
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() {
        scanner.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CommandLineReader commandLineReader = 
                new CommandLineReader(new BufferedCommandProvider());

        commandLineReader.run();
    }
}
```

**AbstractCommandProvider.java**

```
 package net.coderodde.command.line;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * This abstract class defines some commonalities and API for command providers.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jul 26, 2017)
 */
public abstract class AbstractCommandProvider {

    /**
     * The string used for separating adjacent commands.
     */
    protected String commandSeparator;

    /**
     * List of command listeners.
     */
    private final List<CommandListener> commandListenerList = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Processes a line of text.
     * 
     * @param line the line of text.
     */
    public abstract void processLine(String line);

    /**
     * Returns the current command separator string.
     * 
     * @return the command separator string.
     */
    public String getCommandSeparator() {
        return commandSeparator;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the command separator string.
     * 
     * @param commandSeparator the command separator.
     */
    public void setCommandSeparator(String commandSeparator) {
        this.commandSeparator = checkCommandSeparator(commandSeparator);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a command listener to the current listener list.
     * 
     * @param commandListener the command listener to add.
     */
    public void addCommandListener(CommandListener commandListener) {
        if (commandListener != null) {
            commandListenerList.add(commandListener);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes a command listener from the current listener list.
     * 
     * @param commandListener the command listener to remove.
     */
    public void removeCommandListener(CommandListener commandListener) {
        commandListenerList.remove(commandListener);
    }

    /**
     * Broadcasts the command to all command listeners of this provider.
     * 
     * @param command the command to broadcast.
     */
    protected void broadcastCommand(String command) {
        for (CommandListener commandListener : commandListenerList) {
            commandListener.onCommand(command);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks that the command separator is not {@code null} and is not empty.
     * 
     * @param commandSeparator the command separator to check.
     * 
     * @return the input commandSeparator.
     * 
     * @throws NullPointerException if the command separator is {@code null}.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the command separator is empty.
     */
    private String checkCommandSeparator(String commandSeparator) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(commandSeparator, 
                               "The input command separator is null.");

        if (commandSeparator.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The command separator is empty.");
        }

        return commandSeparator;
    }
}
```

**CommandListener.java**

```
package net.coderodde.command.line;

/**
 * This interface defines the API for command line listeners.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jul 26, 2017)
 */
public interface CommandListener {

    /**
     * Called on any new command.
     * 
     * @param command the command text.
     */
    public void onCommand(String command);
}
```

**BufferedCommandProvider.java**

```
package net.coderodde.command.line.support;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import net.coderodde.command.line.AbstractCommandProvider;

/**
 * This class implements a command provider that caches the command lines until
 * they form at least one full command. The commands are assumed to be separated
 * via semicolons. The user may set other command separator.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Jul 26, 2017)
 */
public final class BufferedCommandProvider extends AbstractCommandProvider {

    /**
     * The default command separator.
     */
    private static final String DEFAULT_COMMAND_SEPARATOR = ";";

    /**
     * Buffers the lines that do not yet form a single command.
     */
    private final List<String> bufferedLineList = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * An auxiliary string buffer for manipulating the lines in the buffer list.
     */
    private final StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

    /**
     * Constructs a new buffered command provider using the given command 
     * separator.
     * 
     * @param commandSeparator the string used for separating the commands.
     */
    public BufferedCommandProvider(String commandSeparator) {
        setCommandSeparator(commandSeparator);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a new buffered command provider using the default command
     * separator.
     */
    public BufferedCommandProvider() {
        this(DEFAULT_COMMAND_SEPARATOR);
    }

    /**
     * Processes the line of text.
     * 
     * @param line the line to handle.
     */
    @Override
    public void processLine(String line) {
        bufferedLineList.add(line);
        clearStringBuffer();

        for (String bufferedLine : bufferedLineList) {
            stringBuffer.append(bufferedLine.trim()).append(' ');
        }

        String bufferContent = stringBuffer.toString().trim();
        String[] bufferCommands = bufferContent.split(commandSeparator);
        boolean lastCommandTerminated = 
                bufferContent.endsWith(commandSeparator);

        if (!lastCommandTerminated && bufferCommands.length < 2) {
            // We don't yet have any full command, so it remains stored in the
            // line list.
            return;
        }

        if (lastCommandTerminated) {
            handleTerminated(bufferCommands);
        } else {
            handleNonTerminated(bufferCommands);
        }
    }

    private void clearStringBuffer() {
        stringBuffer.delete(0, stringBuffer.length());
    }

    private void handleTerminated(String[] bufferCommands) {
        for (String bufferedCommand : bufferCommands) {
            String command = bufferedCommand.trim();
            broadcastCommand(command);
        }

        bufferedLineList.clear();
    }

    private void handleNonTerminated(String[] bufferCommands) {
        for (int i = 0; i < bufferCommands.length - 1; ++i) {
            String command = bufferCommands[i].trim();
            broadcastCommand(command);
        }

        bufferedLineList.clear();
        bufferedLineList.add(bufferCommands[bufferCommands.length - 1]);
    }
}
```

## Demo

Possible session might go like this:

> ```
> > this is a
> > multiline command; another
> this is a multiline command;
> this is a multiline command;
> > come on!;
> another come on!;
> another come on!;
> > quit;
> quit;
> quit;
> Bye!
> ```

## Critique request

Please tell me anything that comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some my remarks:

1) Working with `done`:

```
if (command.equals(QUIT_COMMAND)) {
    done = true;
}
```

can be simplified to

```
done = command.equals(QUIT_COMMAND)
```

2) Avoid usage of finalize, better to have a special close method and call it directly at the app end:

```
void closeScanner() {
    scanner.close();
}
```

3) Naming of collections in plural form:

```
private final List<CommandListener> commandListeners = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> bufferedLines = new ArrayList<>();
```

4) The validation of `commandSeparator` can be done in one line if you use Apache commons lang:

```
Validate.notEmpty(commandSeparator, "The commandSeparator couldn't be null or empty.");
```

5) By default all interface methods are already public:

```
void onCommand(String command);
```

6) Better to pass the given value to the parent constructor and remove the setter:

```
public BufferedCommandProvider(String commandSeparator) {
    super(commandSeparator);
}
```

7) Finally you may inline temporary local variables:

```
 broadcastCommand(bufferedCommand.trim());
```